# How can I point to document-object from string-value of document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//How can I make this work:
var key = 'document';
var propy = 'title';
var val = 'a new title';
$(key).prop(propy,val);
//
//As this does
//$(document).prop('title','test');
```

All incoming vars must be strings. I understand the security concerns.

Comment: Your issue is because you're accessing `'document'` not `document`, ie. you're using a string *not* the `document` keyword

Comment: Yeah I know. My question is how to resolve the string value to a pointer of the document object.

Comment: no way jq can resolve it?

Comment: You could use `eval()`, but it's *horrendous* practice to use it. I'd suggest you simply add an `if` condition where if you detect a string of `'document'` you set it to the `document` keyword. Similarly for the `window`. This seems like a needless complication though, if it's for production code.

Comment: Yeah, I know and agree with you. Eval is not an option. If-statement clearly an option but hoped for something more elegant.

Comment: I don't believe there is, but I'd be happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: `foo.bar` === `foo['bar']`

Comment: I don't think there's a foo above document?

Comment: $(window[key]) should work since document is an object off window. But why are you trying to do this. I'm sure i'm missing something as to why you would want to do it this way.

Comment: Well I'm writing a RWD-library that modifies properites css can't. I could try the window-approach but according to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp document is at the very top.

Comment: If that's the case i would just add one line: var selector = (key == 'document' ? document : key); and create the jQuery object off the selector.

Comment: @SeanWessell Sweet! Thanks everyone for your support.